# PowerShell and ServiceNow REST API Dot-Walking Not Working

Tags: powershell, servicenow

I can specify a value in the body (ex: "sys_updated_by"="JSmith") and successfully return that specific record

```
$URL = "https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_item_option_mtom" 
$headers = @{"AUTHORIZATION"="Basic 12345678900987654321"} 
$Body = @{ 
"sysparm_limit"="1" 
"sys_updated_by"="JSmith" 
} 
(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Get -Uri $URL -Body $Body).result

request_item   : @{link=https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_req_item/cc6f59d4c0779100925cad13165a7325; value=cc6f59d4c0779100925cad13165a7325}
sc_item_option : @{link=https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_item_option/d37c591cc0779100925cad13165a7397; value=d37c591cc0779100925cad13165a7397}
sys_updated_by : JSmith
sys_tags       : 
sys_updated_on : 2014-03-27 16:26:24
sys_id         : 006f555cc0779100925cad13165a7377
sys_mod_count  : 0
sys_created_on : 2014-03-27 16:26:24
sys_created_by : JSmith
```

I cannot return the correct record when I dot-walk with request_item.value (or request_item.link, I haven't found anything that works). I used the value returned from above (cc6f59d4c0779100925cad13165a7325), but the query seems to ignore the whole line "request_item.value"="cc6f59d4c0779100925cad13165a7325" and returns the first record in the table instead

```
$URL = "https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_item_option_mtom"
$headers = @{"AUTHORIZATION"="Basic 12345678900987654321"} 
$Body = @{ 
"sysparm_limit"="1"     
"request_item.value"="cc6f59d4c0779100925cad13165a7325" 
} 
(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Get -Uri $URL -Body $Body).result

request_item   : @{link=https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_req_item/00020bbc6892d900925cda2e3d5bf84a; value=00020bbc6892d900925cda2e3d5bf84a}
sc_item_option : @{link=https://domain.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sc_item_option/f2f14bbc6892d900925cda2e3d5bf8d1; value=f2f14bbc6892d900925cda2e3d5bf8d1}
sys_updated_by : CHOLMES
sys_tags       : 
sys_updated_on : 2014-01-13 23:20:06
sys_id         : 00020bbc6892d900925cda2e3d5bf84c
sys_mod_count  : 0
sys_created_on : 2014-01-13 23:20:06
sys_created_by : CHOLMES
```

Comment: If you assign the result to a variable, like so `$a = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Get -Uri $URL -Body $Body).result`, what happens when you try to call `$a.request_item.Link`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what HTTP request you're making? Seems like a GET, but it has a request body? At any rate, you might try using the sysparm_query parameter to specify the encoded query. If you're not sure where to get the encoded query, you can build the query in the list view, right click on the query breadcrumb and select "Copy query". Hope this helps.

Comment: @FoxDeploy  When saved to a variable, the data is available in $a.request_item.Link.

Comment: @Silas - I'm not the most familiar with the ServiceNow web interface, where specifically can I generate the encoded query?  I'll start poking around.

Comment: This seems to do it:  "https:// domain.service-now.com/sc_item_option_mtom.do?CSV&sysparm_query=request_item=***sys_id***"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it: "https:// domain.service-now.com/sc_item_option_mtom.do?CSV&sysparm_query=request_item=***sy‌​s_id***"